# Sybase stored procedure taking too long

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor, sybase, sql-optimization

The following stored proc is running 4 hrs. Is there anyway I can optimize it to bring down execution time under 10 mins?

Table #TbTemp has 150k rows. And the cursor is looping 150k times.

Since I'm dealing with Temp tables, I will have full control on creating any indices -etc.

Since cursors should be avoided, any alternate solution?

```
declare tmpCur cursor
for
select LnNo,instDrftCreatnDt
from   #TbTemp
for read only

open tmpCur

while (1 = 1)
begin   --{
    fetch tmpCur into @LnNo,@Dt

    insert into #TmpLnPmt
            (RecTyp,InstNo,LnNo,TotCurChrgdFactr,PmtTyp,
            CurrChrgdFactr,CurrPmtAmt,PrevCmptdPmtAmt,NetCmptdPmtAmt)
    select  '01', @InstNo, @LnNo, @TotCurChrgdFactr, pc.PmtTyp,
            0, 0, pc.cmptdPmtAmt, 0-pc.cmptdPmtAmt
    from    Ln l, Pmt pt, PmtCmpnt pc
    where   l.LnNo = @LnNo
    and     pt.mbsLoanPID = l.identifier
    and     pt.instDrftCreatnDt = @Dt
    and     pc.paymentComponentsPaymentPID = pt.identifier
    and     pc.PmtTyp not in (select   PmtTyp
                    from    #TbTemp
                    where   LnNo = @LnNo)
    and     not exists (select  1 from #TmpLnPmt
                where   LnNo = @LnNo
                and     PmtTyp = pc.PmtTyp)
    end --}
close tmpCur
deallocate cursor tmpCur
```

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not just cursors that should be avoided but any looping or row by row iterations.  RDBMS is based on the concept of sets, and optimized to work on sets, not rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way without using `CURSOR`

```
INSERT INTO #tmplnpmt 
            (rectyp, 
             instno, 
             lnno, 
             totcurchrgdfactr, 
             pmttyp, 
             currchrgdfactr, 
             currpmtamt, 
             prevcmptdpmtamt, 
             netcmptdpmtamt) 
SELECT '01', 
       @InstNo, 
       a.lnno, 
       @TotCurChrgdFactr, 
       pc.pmttyp, 
       0, 
       0, 
       pc.cmptdpmtamt, 
       0 - pc.cmptdpmtamt 
FROM   ln l 
       INNER JOIN pmt pt 
               ON pt.mbsloanpid = l.identifier 
       INNER JOIN pmtcmpnt pc 
               ON pc.paymentcomponentspaymentpid = pt.identifier 
       INNER JOIN #tbtemp a 
               ON l.lnno = a.lnno 
                  AND pt.instdrftcreatndt = a.instdrftcreatndt 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT pmttyp 
                   FROM   #tbtemp t 
                   WHERE  t.pmttyp = pc.pmttyp) 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM   #tmplnpmt a 
                              INNER JOIN #tbtemp b 
                                      ON a.lnno = b.lnno 
                                         AND pmttyp = pc.pmttyp)
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo when copying. #instpmtcmpnt should also be #tbtemp in original question. Can you please check again? I appreciate your help!!